# Cors problem with nginx/django from react app on docker

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, docker-compose, cors

I have a question about cors implementation in django.
Having a problem with setting the correct cors values.
My deployment is on docker.
I have a deployed 3 containers:

- **backend**: Django + DRF as backend (expose 8000 port)
- **Nginx** to server my backend (use exposed 8000 port and set it to 1338)
- **frontend** React app used with nginx (uses port 1337)

Everything is on localhost.
I use axios from frontend to call get/post requests. (I call to 1338 port then I think it is redirected to internal service on 8000 port)
For backend I had to install django-cors-headers package to work with CORS.
I think I set up it correctly. But there are scenarios where it does not work.

In settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
"corsheaders",
]
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
"django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
...
]
```

Nginx.conf for nginx image:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:1337;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

**First scenario**

In settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

No get/post requests work. Get message:
*CORS Multiple Origin Not Allowed*

**Second scenario**
In settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:1337"]
```

Works with get requests, but does not work with post requests.

For post requests:

- options with error: CORS Missing Allow Header
- post with error: NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

[image]

It works if I am not using nginx for backend.

Adding request headers as requested in the comment.

[image]

I am not sure what else could I add here. So my deployed project is here (it also is easy to launch if you have docker on your machine:
https://gitlab.com/k.impolevicius/app-001

Comment: Can you given an example of a failing POST request? Does it perhaps contain a non-standard header not [allowed by CORS](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#cors_allow_headers-sequencestr)?

Comment: I ca try tomorrow. I am far away. By the way, you can try to launch it. I added repo to it.

Comment: You write that you call the _backend_ on port 1338, but in your repo it seems vice versa: The frontend is called at http://localhost:1338 and requests go to the backend at http://localhost:1337. In that case, you also need `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:1338"]`.

Comment: Share your nginx configuration as well. Also are you using any prefix with the urls that you passed in `CORS_URLS_REGEX` ? Also I feel the configuration is missing in nginx

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Yes frontend is 1338, but it calls nginx on port 1337, which calls 8000 (exposed port) backend server.
If you have docker it can be launched and checked with different options. That is why I created this project.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I added needed nginx.conf file. By the way you can try to look at gitlab repo, which I added.

Comment: @K.I. it seems the problem is your backend and also the nginx sends access control allow headers and the client is being confused due to this. Just check the raw response from nginx to your client and try to hide unnecessary headers with "proxy_hide_header"

Comment: Have you changed `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:1337"]` to `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:1338"]`?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen it does not work if I change it to 1338. Now even get does not work.
By the way you can try to run it. It is prepared for docker. docker-compose up -d --build

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come across this issue a while back, and I think the issue is with the headers.
In the MDN docs, it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) that other than for the simple requests, we'll get preflighted requests with [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) method. There are 3 main headers that we need to send in response in your case

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1337
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

From the looks of it you have configured the first header and you should be seeing it in the network tab too, and since the error is about missing allow headers, you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header
to your nginx file

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
```

Seeing your network tab on the requested headers will give more context here, generally you should be seeing `Access-Control-Request-Method` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` headers in the `OPTIONS` request. If there are some headers that you aren't allowing, please write an nginx rule for the same. You can look into [this solution](https://serverfault.com/a/716283) for more reference

Comment: @K.I. Can you share the screenshots of your request and response headers from the network tab so we can identify the issue more clearly?

Comment: Added to post as asked,

Comment: This solution you referenced in your answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, seems that problem is in `axios.post` not in Django or nginx.

Because if you do curl post or post from drf browsable api, it works fine:

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:1337/Country/ \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"name": "other"}'
{"id":6,"name":"other"}%
```

But react app generates this `OPTIONS` request:

```
app-001-backend-1   | [13/May/2022 05:56:20] "OPTIONS /Country/ HTTP/1.0" 200 0
app-001-nginx-1     | 192.168.240.1 - - [13/May/2022:05:56:20 +0000] "OPTIONS /Country/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://localhost:1338/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15" "-"
```

Comment: Yes I know that I can run it from dfr browsable api. But how to fix it in code?
I run standard axios post call in frontend/src/App.js:   
     const handleInsert = async () => {
       const response = await axios.post(
         "http://localhost:1337/Country/",
         country
       );
     };

Some headers disappears :) during request from fronted?